# GMSPlace method isOpen return value GMSPlaceOpenStatus Value is always "unknown"

Tags: swift, google-maps

The data such as openingHours is normally taken, but I can't confirm whether it is open with "isOpen".

Answer (score 0):

This issue really looks legitimate. Thanks for reporting.

We have already reported this to our Engineering team. Please star this https://issuetracker.google.com/160110011 in our **Google Issue Tracker** to receive further updates.

Answer (score 0):

When I added `UInt(GMSPlaceField.utcOffsetMinutes.rawValue) |` to GMSPlaceField it worked fine